# Conic programming: minimizing the l_2 norm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

It is widely known that the following optimization problem
\begin{equation}
\text{min}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\lVert{x}\rVert_2
\end{equation}
is equivalent to the problem
\begin{equation}
\text{min}_{x,q} \hspace{3pt}q\\
\hspace{25pt} s.t. \hspace{15pt} q\geq\lVert{x}\rVert_2.
\end{equation}

I don't quite understand the constraint here: in the original problem, we try to minimize $\lVert x \rVert_2$, but in the "equivalent" problem, we try to minimize a quantity ***that may be strictly greater than*** $\lVert x \rVert_2$. In this case, why are the two problems equivalent?

Besides this specific problem, when we call two optimization problems ***equivalent***, what do we actually mean?

Answer (score 2):

At optimal solution, we must have $q = \|x\|_2$.

If you have $(q_1, x)$ that satifies $q_1 > \|x\|_2$ and you can claim that it is optimal, I will choose $(\|x\|_2, x)$ and we can check that it is a better solution and contradicts your optimality claim.

We say two problems are equivalent if by solving one, we can recover the solution for the other one.